# what exactly is plsql function returning if it just return returntype

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, dml

I'm having a hard time understanding the below plsql function. what exactly does the function return and what exactly does the function do?

```
      function getsysparm(a_name varchar2,

                          a_default varchar2 := null,

                          a_date    sys_params.date_expires%type := null) 

                  return  varchar2;
```

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. I feel like an idiot staring at a function declaration for 10min!

Answer (score 1):

That's not a function, it's just a function declaration, and from the looks of it, probably in a package spec.  You need to look in the package body to see the actual code for the function.

Answer (score 0):

Function accepts 3 parameters: one is mandatory (`a_name`), while another two are optional.

It returns a *string* (value whose datatype is `VARCHAR2`), for example "Abby" or "Stack Overflow" or "x".

What does it exactly do? Who knows ... you didn't post any code. See whether

```
select text
from user_source
where name = 'GETSYSPARM'
```

returns something you could have a look at.